# C++ inheritance in template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, parameters, parameter-passing

I need to pass template as function argument, but template must accept all inherited objects.

For example:

```
template <class T>
class Template {
public:
    Template() {}
};

// IMPORTANT: must accept all children of "Base"
class Test {
    Template<Base> *pointer;
public:
    Test(Template<Base> *pointer) {...}
};


main() {
    Template<Base> *base = new Template<Base>();
    Template<Child1> *child = new Template<Child1>();

    Test *test1 = new Test(base);    // WORKING
    // NEXT LINE IS IMPORTANT:
    Test *test2 = new Test(child);   // ERROR: no matching function for call to 'Test::Test(Template<Child1>*&)'
}


class Base {...};
class Child1 : public Base {...};
class Child2 : public Base {...};
..
```

I need the most effective way, how to store template in "Test" class, that will accept all children classes. I have lot's of children classes.

1) Is it possible to make some up casting (static_cast) for Child class in argument? It will be good to use it inside of "Template" or inside of "Test" class. Not, when creating new "Test" object, because there will be lot's of new objects.

2) Or pass argument without template argument `Test(Template *pointer) {...}`?

Or how to solve it?

Comment: `Template<Child1>` is totally unrelated to `Template<Base>`. They're completely different classes. Depending on what you're trying to do, type erasure may be a viable option.

Comment: Is there anything that prevents you from having a base class (non-templated) to Template<Base> and store this in your Test class instead?

Comment: @coyotte508: yes, acceptable solution, but I would like to know, if there is any straight solution for template parameter inheritance.

Comment: @Cornstalks: thanks, will try type erasure

Answer (score 2):

The reason that the thing you want to do doesn't work is because template types don't observe inheritance in typename parameters.

```
Template<Base> *base
```

and

```
Template<Child1> *child
```

are completely different types. Trying to use one in place of the other is like trying to pass an `int` to a function that has a `string` parameter.

That said, I believe you have two viable options here.

## #1 Make `Test` a template too

One option would be to make `Test` a template too:

```
template <typename T>
class Test {
    T *pointer;
public:
    Test(T *pointer) {...}
};
```

This would allow the `Test` object to work with whatever object was passed to it.

## #2 Use an interface

Alternatively, by creating an interface, and implementing that interface in `Template`, you can pass your interface to the `Test` class:

```
/**
 * Interface that declares the virtual methods that
 * will be used by your Test class.
 */
class ITemplate {
public:
    virtual ~ITemplate() {}

    // Define your methods here.
    virtual void Foo() = 0;
    virtual void Bar() = 0;
    virtual void Baz() = 0;
}

/**
 * Concrete ITemplate implementation.
 */
template <class T>
class Template : public ITemplate {
public:
    Template() {}
    virtual ~Template() {}

    virtual void Foo() override {}
    virtual void Bar() override {}
    virtual void Baz() override {}

};

class Test {
    ITemplate *pointer;
public:
    Test(ITemplate *pointer) {...}
};
```

This has the advantage that you can modify your `Template` class without affecting your `Test` class, because the `Test` class works with `ITemplate` interfaces instead of concrete objects. The downside of this is that you incur the cost of virtual function lookups, which may be undesirable if you're trying to write extremely efficient code.

Comment: I tried the first solution before, but you have to specific template type 2 times - for Template and for Test class. I wanted to know any better solution. If no more solutions will be presented in shore time, I will accept the interface solution. Thanks!

Comment: I have one problem with interface solution. How to use methods depending on type? For example I have in "Template" class: `void Foo(T) override {}`, how can I make interface for that? I can't have in ITemplate: `virtual void Foo(Base) = 0;`. Neither in Template class: `T Foo() override {}` and in ITemplate: `virtual Base Foo() = 0;`

Comment: @Nick - I don't think you can do what you want to do with an interface. `T` would be undefined unless you made `Foo` a template function, but you cannot have a virtual template function.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Is it possible to make some up casting (static_cast) for Child class in argument? It will be good to use it inside of "Template" or inside of "Test" class. Not, when creating new "Test" object, because there will be lot's of new objects.

I don't exactly understand what you're suggesting. It won't be possible to cast an unrelated pointer to another.

> 2) Or pass argument without template argument

No. Templates can not be function arguments.

What you could do, is make `Template<T>` implicitly convertible to other instances of `Template`:

```
template <class T>
class Template {
public:
    // ...

    template<class U>
    Template(const Template<U>&);
};
```

Depending on how the converting constructor is implemented, it may impose restrictions on `U`.

And further, if you were to store a `Template<Base>` instance within `Test` instead of a pointer:

```
class Test {
    Template<Base> member;
    // ...
};
```

Then, you could accept the `Template<Base>` by value (to copy) or by rvalue-reference (to move) to the constructor. A `Template<Child>` would be implicitly converted to `Template<Base>`:

```
class Test {
    Template<Base> member;
public:
    Test(Template<Base> argument) {/* ... */}
};
```

This approach is the same as is used to allow implicit up casting of the standard smart pointer types.

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting solution, only one problem is, that it will create a copy of the Template<Base> in Test object. If there will be a similar solution with pointer (or move), it will be good.

Comment: @Nick you should consider whether creating a copy of `Template<Base>` is a bad thing, and if it is, then why would it be. If you would like to instead move, then that would certainly be possible by using `Test(Template<Base>&& argument)`. Storing a pointer won't be an option because the implicitly converted `Template<Base>` is a temporary and will be destroyed after the call to the constructor ends so a pointer to it would be left dangling.